# Most concise way to get max(A.x) in a Collection<A>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class `Person` defined with those attributes :

```
private String name;
private String surname;
private Date birthday;
```

I want to get the max of the birthdays in a `Collection<Person>`.

In **Java 7**, without external libraries, I would do it like this :

```
public Date maxAgeJava7(Collection<Person> persons) {
  Date max = null;
  for (Person person : persons) {
    if (max == null || person.getBirthday().after(max)) {
      max = person.getBirthday();
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```

Now, In **Java 8**, it is possible to write it like this :

```
public Date maxAgeJava8(Collection<Person> persons) {
  return persons.stream().map(Person::getBirthday).max((Date d1, Date d2)-> d1.compareTo(d2)).get();
}
```

This is far better **BUT** I don't like this part :

```
(Date d1, Date d2)-> d1.compareTo(d2)
```

As Date `implements Comparable`, is there a way to tell Java to use the `compareTo()` method, without having to explicitly write it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`max` requires a `Comparator` as parameter.

I think the shortest thing you can do is to call the method `compareTo` using method reference.

```
public Date maxAgeJava8(Collection<Person> persons) {
    return persons.stream().map(Person::getBirthday).max(Date::compareTo).get();
}
```

Also note that you don't need to use a `Stream` to accomplish this. You could simply use `Collections.max` providing a custom comparator:

```
public Date maxAgeJava8(Collection<Person> persons) {
    return Collections.max(persons, Comparator.comparing(Person::getBirthday)).getBirthday();
}
```

Comment: This is great :) Can you explain why it works? `Date::compareTo` is a method reference. Why does the compiler sees it as a Comparator?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle It works because the method reference actually is a comparator, not a result of a function call like `compareTo()`. To be more clear: You can write `Comparator<Date> comp = Date::compareTo` and than parse this to max: `max(comp)`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle ifLoop says it all. Also note that the equivalent lamdba for `Date::compareTo` is `(Date a, Date b) -> a.compareTo(b)`, which is what you've already done. So you could also do `Comparator<Date> comp = (Date a, Date b) -> a.compareTo(b);`

Comment: If you need a `Comparator` for `Comparable` objects you can use `Comparator.naturalOrder()` to get one. Thus: `return persons.stream().map(Person::getBirthday).max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();`

Comment: @ZouZou `Date::compareTo` references a non-static method that takes one argument. I don't understand why it is elligible to replace `Comparator.compare(T o1, T o2)` which is a static method that takes 2 arguments. Does java automatically replace `Date.this.compareTo(b)` with `Comparator.compareTo(this, b)` ?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle `Date::compareTo` will have the parameter list `(Date d1, Date d2)` and the method reference will invoke `d1.compareTo(d2)`. So it would be the same as if you implement an anonymous class of Comparator. I'm not sure about this though as I didn't get enough deeply about how method references works. May this help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html